# How to avoid items overlap together when set position random?

Tags: java, android

on xml layout, I have a FrameLayout with no child. Then I add a list buttons programatically into this framelayout by this code below:

```
private void addNumbers(){ // Numbers is set with random position

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("" + i);
        btn.setId(i);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        int leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(widthScreen - btnSize ); 
        int topMargin = new Random().nextInt(heightScreen - btnSize);    
        lp.leftMargin = leftMargin;
        lp.topMargin = topMargin;

        btn.setLayoutParams(lp);
        framelayout1.addView(btn);
        //framelayout2.addView(btn);

    }
}
```

And some buttons overlap together, I do not want to happen this. How to avoid this problem ? Thanks in advance.

P/s: Sorry I can not upload image from my company, all upload > 4K is reject, please tell me if the question is not clear.